# Custom template bypassing to pager to index.php

Tags: templates

I have custom layout and its a template page, but for some strange reason, the custom template is loading up index.php. I double checked in my editor, the template is selected correctly, still it shows content of "Default page" or index.php . How can i debug it, on what is going wrong?

Comment: Please provide your .htaccess code. The issue may be there

Comment: @IgnatB. Its untouched, as it is when you install xampp

Comment: Do you've `page.php` in your theme?

Comment: @IgnatB. yes i have page.php

Comment: Try to flush_rewrite_rules() or Settings->Permalinks->click"Update". Additionally ensure that index.php displays instead of page template (put a custom "foo bar" at the top of index.php)